# Подключить библиотеки Selenium к проекту AndroidStudio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Пишу программу на `Android`, которая должна в `WebView` загружать сайт, находить на нем элементы и нажимать их.
При подключении библиотек `Selenium-api`, `Selenium-java`, `SeleniumRemoteDriver` ругается на дубликаты файлов в библиотеках:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug'.
>   java.io.IOException: Can't write [C:\Users\Java\Downloads\selendroid-master\WebView_20\app\build\intermediates\multi-dex\debug\componentClasses.jar] (Can't read [C:\Users\Java\Downloads\selendroid-master\WebView_20\selenium-remote-driver-2.48.2\selenium-remote-driver-2.48.2.jar(;;;;;;**.class)] (Duplicate zip entry [selenium-remote-driver-2.48.2.jar:org/openqa/selenium/remote/Augmentable.class]))

Помогите исправить ошибку при компиляции (сборке)...

Вот ссылка на мой проект на `GitHub`: https://github.com/brat926/SeleniumAndroid